# Segfault everywhere even when reinstalling the OS

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault

Lately my PC keeps getting segmentation fault, everywhere, on almost every apps (thunderbird, firefox, chromium, google-chrome, wine, byobu)

here's the last few output of dmesg:

```
[ 1474.815026] traps: chrome[2134] general protection ip:7f38bb407aef sp:7fff59358350 error:0 in chrome[7f38b9b18000+51d2000]
[ 3867.645750] traps: chrome[10568] general protection ip:7fb4864ed072 sp:7fffceacd7a0 error:0 in chrome[7fb4848e0000+51d2000]
[ 5075.793435] traps: chrome[5951] general protection ip:7fb486530bbe sp:7fffceaceaa0 error:0 in chrome[7fb4848e0000+51d2000]
[ 6232.893991] traps: chrome[6031] general protection ip:7fb486530bbe sp:7fffceacd4f0 error:0 in chrome[7fb4848e0000+51d2000]
[ 6270.321944] traps: chrome[15562] general protection ip:7fb4864f0150 sp:7fffceacedb8 error:0 in chrome[7fb4848e0000+51d2000]
[ 6284.271553] traps: HTMLParserThrea[15673] general protection ip:7fb4869ed85b sp:7fb4702b6910 error:0 in chrome[7fb4848e0000+51d2000]
[ 6390.844552] traps: chromium[15700] general protection ip:7f63e065b76e sp:7fff367a4ba0 error:0 in chromium[7f63debd0000+5864000]
[ 7645.971546] traps: chromium[18004] general protection ip:7f63e0653e64 sp:7fff36799df0 error:0 in chromium[7f63debd0000+5864000]
[ 7927.389333] traps: chrome[18743] general protection ip:7f3acfd00150 sp:7fff42406438 error:0 in chrome[7f3ace0f0000+51d2000]
[ 8075.937762] traps: chrome[18674] general protection ip:7f3acfd00150 sp:7fff42406438 error:0 in chrome[7f3ace0f0000+51d2000]
[ 8159.218088] chromium[2966]: segfault at 180816000388 ip 00007f63e06a62c5 sp 00007fff367a47a0 error 4 in chromium[7f63debd0000+5864000]
[ 8515.463384] traps: chromium[20359] general protection ip:7f63e06bfcdf sp:7fff36798100 error:0 in chromium[7f63debd0000+5864000]
[ 8540.132912] traps: komodo[14107] trap stack segment ip:7f81c87b158a sp:7ffff8021890 error:0
[ 8745.165817] Key type dns_resolver registered
[ 8745.174187] FS-Cache: Netfs 'cifs' registered for caching
[ 8745.174286] Key type cifs.spnego registered
[ 8745.174293] Key type cifs.idmap registered
[ 8771.698855] traps: chrome[21109] general protection ip:7f3acfd038ce sp:7fff42406390 error:0 in chrome[7f3ace0f0000+51d2000]
[ 8956.317097] Chrome_IOThread[2374]: segfault at 39 ip 00007f18935a8d00 sp 00007f18775279a8 error 6 in chromium[7f1892658000+5864000]
[ 8959.347113] traps: chromium[22247] general protection ip:7f72f97c6f0a sp:7fffeb74ac90 error:0 in chromium[7f72f7db8000+5864000]
[ 8979.590397] traps: chromium[22514] general protection ip:7f72f983931e sp:7fffeb753070 error:0 in chromium[7f72f7db8000+5864000]
[ 8982.106736] chromium[22627]: segfault at 96dfb2e4e0 ip 00007f72f9842bd8 sp 00007fffeb754670 error 4 in chromium[7f72f7db8000+5864000]
[ 9031.249176] traps: chromium[22333] general protection ip:7f72f97068d0 sp:7fffeb7546f8 error:0 in chromium[7f72f7db8000+5864000]
```

And first few second during execution of `firefox`:

```
(process:23183): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
Segmentation fault
```

When using `gdb firefox`:

```
[New Thread 0x7fffc33ff700 (LWP 22838)]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7fffda3ff700 (LWP 22692)]
0x00007ffff386e905 in ?? () from /usr/lib/firefox/libxul.so
```

On `chromium`:

```
[2333:2374:0731/105842:ERROR:raw_channel_posix.cc(139)] recvmsg: Connection reset by peer
[2333:2374:0731/105842:ERROR:channel.cc(297)] RawChannel fatal error (type 1)

*snip*

[2333:2374:0731/105903:ERROR:raw_channel_posix.cc(139)] recvmsg: Connection reset by peer
[2333:2374:0731/105903:ERROR:channel.cc(297)] RawChannel fatal error (type 1)
../../third_party/tcmalloc/chromium/src/free_list.h:118] Memory corruption detected. 
Segmentation fault
```

When using `google-chrome-stable`:

```
[18495:18528:0731/105816:ERROR:raw_channel_posix.cc(139)] recvmsg: Connection reset by peer
[18495:18528:0731/105816:ERROR:channel.cc(297)] RawChannel fatal error (type 1)
--2014-07-31 10:58:16--  https://clients2.google.com/cr/report
Resolving clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)... 111.94.248.52, 111.94.248.38, 111.94.248.18, ...
Connecting to clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)|111.94.248.52|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘/dev/fd/3’

    [<=>                                          ] 0           --.-K/s              
Crash dump id: 8d43b07b2158483d
```

When using `thunderbird`:

```
[Exception... "'Method not implemented' when calling method: 
[imIAccount::loadBuddy]"  nsresult: "0x80004001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/components/imContacts.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 1237"  data: no]

*snip*

[Exception... "'Method not implemented' when calling method: [imIAccount::loadBuddy]"  nsresult: "0x80004001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/components/imContacts.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 1237"  data: no]
Segmentation fault
```

And many more.. Currently I'm using Manjaro Linux:

```
Linux archpc 3.14.13-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Jul 18 09:02:40 UTC 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Previously I'm using latest ArchLinux, it also happened..

I'm seriously don't know what to do.. It's only happened since past 3 weeks, before that, Chrome and Chromium only crash "Aw snap" once in a while.

Here's the list of installed program in my computer: http://pastie.org/9433158

Could anyone help me to find the causation of this problem?

Comment: kindly edit, link you mentioned is incomplete it is home page of pastie.org.

Comment: ah sorry, it's http://pastie.org/9433158

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like a hardware fault. Segfaults across the whole system can be caused by bad sectors on the disk or bad memory.

[Run a memory test](http://www.memtest.org/) and see if there's some faulty memory that is causing your issue.

After that if the memory test does not find an issue, I would run a `badblocks` scan on your hard drive.

Comment: ok, i will run `fsck -vccky /dev/sdX1` on all partition

Comment: @Kokizzu I would do the memory test first.

Comment: yes, it's RAM problem, corruption occurs on 46xx MB and 13xxxMB T__T what should I do?

Comment: Time for new RAM !

Comment: could you follow up the next question http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/147587/27996 thank you ^^