# How to prevent certain memory location to be accessed

Tags: memory

I have 2 corrupted RAM module, on offset: 46xx MB and 13xxx MB (from `memtest` on boot)
How to prevent Linux to access/alloc/read/write into those offset?

Here's the result of `memtester` on ~1000 MB to ~1400 MB:

http://pastie.org/9433211

Comment: The link seems to not be specific.

Comment: ah sorry, it's larger than 64KB, i'll reupload, it's: http://pastie.org/9433211

Comment: My answer is still "Get New RAM"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `badram` kernel patch..
It allocate memory on certain address so it could not be used.

http://rick.vanrein.org/linuxa/badram/

http://blog.eracc.com/2011/02/02/linux-with-badram-saves-the-day/

or `badmem`

http://badmem.sourceforge.net/docu/BadMEM-HOWTO.html

or turn of address after certain point

http://gquigs.blogspot.com/2009/01/bad-memory-howto.html